# ansible hostname replace with three digit IP

Tags: ansible, hostname

How can I replace the hostname with the last three digits of IP address:

Example:

```
IP: 192.168.0.1
Hostname: webserver001
```

I want my hostname to be replace based on the last three digits of the IP address but what I get is `webserver1` instead of `webserver001`, how can I pad leading zeros.

below is the code I use.

```
- hostname: name={{ hostname.replace('*', ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0].split('.')[3]) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
name={{ "webserver%03d"|format(ansible_default_ipv4.address.split(".")[3]|int) }}
```

using the `format` filter, along with the `int` filter, allows padding numbers with zeros.

Exemple with `test.yml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: test jinja capabilities
      debug: msg={{ "webserver%03d"|format(ansible_default_ipv4.address.split(".")[2]|int) }}
```

When run, it gives

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml    

PLAY     ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup]     *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test jinja capabilities] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "webserver001"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0        failed=0
```

for localhost having IP `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the big help.. appreciate it a lot.. this exactly works as expected.